# Different versions of lowercase R

Tags: handwriting

I use two different versions of lowercase R (often subconsciously) while writing in English for my studies. Is this something unacceptable in cases like exams or assignment submissions?

No one ever complained about it, but do others also exhibit such behaviour in English handwriting?

P.S. This is relevant to English handwriting practice, so I apologise if this question is not acceptable in this community. Thanks.

Comment: Lowercase "r" is a difficult letter to pull off "correctly" in cursive handwriting.  Don't get too anxious about not being consistent with it.

Comment: Native handwriters use a number of versions, some only final, some appearing anywhere in the word. All are recognized and there is no consistency. Handwriting is your own affair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this something unacceptable in cases like exams or assignment submissions?

**No**, it is of course acceptable, as long as your handwriting is legible and understandable. In English, there are two different ways to hand-write a lowercase "r": the cursive way and the non-cursive way. Both are fine as long as you write them clearly, and both are interchangeable as well.

> do others also exhibit such behaviour in English handwriting?

**Yes**. As others have mentioned, handwriting is up to the individual who is writing. It can change at any moment's notice and you can do whatever you want with it. As long as it's legible, it's fine.